# Autoload a Paypal PHP SDK in Drupal 7

Tags: php, drupal, paypal, drupal-7, composer-php

I am new in creating a custom module in drupal 7 and basically I want to include the paypal PHP SDK library into my custom module.

This is my example path of my custom module

> drupal/sites/all/modules/custom/custom_paypal

I've created the necessary files like .info and .module file for it my problem is when I am including the autoload.php from the composer install in my custom module that creates the directories and file

> vendor->autoload.php, vendor->composer, and vendor->paypal

The vendor paypal where the library is found is autoloaded by the autoload.php. I've tried using this one into my .info file:

```
files[] = vendor/autoload.php
```

but it didn't work I've also tried this one

```
function custom_paypal_init() {
  require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
}
```

now I am instantiating a new class in the custom form I've made but it prompts an error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Payment' not found

Which is in the Paypal SDK,

Can anyone help me how to properly include the classes of this API? Thanks!

Comment: I'm in exactly the same place. Were you able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fix the problem by using `require_once` method on the very first line of my custom module:

```
require_once (__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');
```